# Arduino turn char into a string

Tags: arduino, char

I am trying to turn a char into a string so I can extract the values I am interested in, however it just appears empty.
The variable I am interested in is content.

I am performing a get and it returns a JSON object. And want to extract the sunrise and sunset values.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

EthernetClient client;

const char* server =    "api.sunrise-sunset.org";                  // server's address
const char* resource =  "/json?lat=53.440&lng=0.200&date=today";   // http resource
const unsigned long BAUD_RATE = 9600;                              // serial connection speed
const unsigned long HTTP_TIMEOUT = 10000;                          // max respone time from server
const size_t MAX_CONTENT_SIZE = 512;                               // max size of the HTTP response

// ARDUINO entry point #1: runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
initSerial();
initEthernet();
}

// ARDUINO entry point #2: runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
 if (connect(server)) {
 if (sendRequest(server, resource) && skipResponseHeaders()) {
  char response[MAX_CONTENT_SIZE]; 
  String str(response);
  Serial.println(str);


char* field;
char* sunset;
char* sunrise;

field = strtok(response,"{,");

while (field != NULL)
{
    field = strtok (NULL, ",}");

    if(field != NULL)
    {
        if(strstr(field, "sunrise") != NULL)
        {
            int length = strlen(field);
           sunrise = new char[length + 1];
           strncpy(sunrise, field, length + 1);         // +1 to copy a terminating null as well
        }

        if(strstr(field, "sunset") != NULL)
        {
            int length = strlen(field);
            sunset = new char[length + 1];              
            strncpy(sunset, field, length + 1);         // +1 to copy a terminating null as well
        }
    }
}

//Serial.println("SUNRISE DATA: %s\n\n", sunrise);
//Serial.println("SUNSET  DATA: %s\n\n", sunset);

free(sunrise);  // do not forget to free the memory if not needed anymore
free(sunset);   // do not forget to free the memory if not needed anymore
}
disconnect();
}
wait();
}
// Initialize Serial port
void initSerial() {
 Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
 while (!Serial) {
 ;  // wait for serial port to initialize
}
Serial.println("Serial ready");
}
// Initialize Ethernet library
void initEthernet() {
 byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
 byte ip[] = { 192,168,0,202 };

 if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet");
  return;
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet ready");
  delay(1000);
  }
  // Open connection to the HTTP server
  bool connect(const char* hostName) {
   Serial.print("Connect to ");
   Serial.println(hostName);

   bool ok = client.connect(hostName, 80);

   Serial.println(ok ? "Connected" : "Connection Failed!");
   return ok;
  }
  // Send the HTTP GET request to the server
  bool sendRequest(const char* host, const char* resource) {
   Serial.print("GET ");
   Serial.println(resource);
    client.print("GET ");
    client.print(resource);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(server);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    return true;
   }
   // Skip HTTP headers so that we are at the beginning of the response's body
   bool skipResponseHeaders() {
    // HTTP headers end with an empty line
   char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
   client.setTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT);
  bool ok = client.find(endOfHeaders);
   if (!ok) {
   Serial.println("No response or invalid response!");
   }
   return ok;
  }
 void disconnect() {
  Serial.println("Disconnect");
  client.stop();
 }
 // Pause for a 1 minute
 void wait() {
  Serial.println("Wait 60 seconds");
  delay(60000);
 }
```

[image: garbled get data]

Comment: It is unclear. Please name your variable that you want to convert. You are talking about this array `char response[MAX_CONTENT_SIZE];`?

Comment: Sorry had put in the code not the text, the variable content. this is what I would like to be a string so I can extract the parts I am interested in thanks.

Comment: how does content get populated?  I can't see any reference

Comment: I suppose via the `readReponseContent(response, sizeof(response));` function.

Comment: yes its the variable created as part of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding from your side. Certainly you want to process the response of the server and according to your code, this is `char response[MAX_CONTENT_SIZE]` where the response is stored.

Now this **already is a string**, more or less. An array of characters, `char`s. Definiton from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm).

> Strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character '\0'. Thus a null-terminated string contains the characters that comprise the string followed by a null.

---

You can extract the relevant parts from it straight away.

Your response should look like something like this, according to [sunrise-sunset.org/api](http://sunrise-sunset.org/api). Note that I just copied the data into an array for testing purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CONTENT_SIZE 512

char response[MAX_CONTENT_SIZE] = \
"{\
\"results\":\
{\
\"sunrise\":\"7:27:02 AM\",\
\"sunset\":\"5:05:55 PM\",\
\"solar_noon\":\"12:16:28 PM\",\
\"day_length\":\"9:38:53\",\
\"civil_twilight_begin\":\"6:58:14 AM\",\
\"civil_twilight_end\":\"5:34:43 PM\",\
\"nautical_twilight_begin\":\"6:25:47 AM\",\
\"nautical_twilight_end\":\"6:07:10 PM\",\
\"astronomical_twilight_begin\":\"5:54:14 AM\",\
\"astronomical_twilight_end\":\"6:38:43 PM\"\
},\
\"status\":\"OK\"\
}";
```

---

You can easily process it using [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function from `string.h`. Using a `{,` delimiter first will separate `"result":{` from `"sunrise ...`. Then you can use a `},` delimiter.

With [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) you can check for `"sunrise"` and `"sunset"` field, and if you find them you can copy their value into a new string with [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/).

```
int main()
{
    char* field;
    char* sunset;
    char* sunrise;

    field = strtok(response,"{,");

    while (field != NULL)
    {
        field = strtok (NULL, ",}");

        if(field != NULL)
        {
            if(strstr(field, "sunrise") != NULL)
            {
                int length = strlen(field);
                sunrise = malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1); // +1 for terminating null character '\0'
                strncpy(sunrise, field, length + 1);         // +1 to copy a terminating null as well
            }

            if(strstr(field, "sunset") != NULL)
            {
                int length = strlen(field);
                sunset = malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1); // +1 for terminating null character '\0'
                strncpy(sunset, field, length + 1);         // +1 to copy a terminating null as well
            }
        }
    }

    printf("SUNRISE DATA: %s\n\n", sunrise);
    printf("SUNSET  DATA: %s\n\n", sunset);

    free(sunrise);  // do not forget to free the memory if not needed anymore
    free(sunset);   // do not forget to free the memory if not needed anymore

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
SUNRISE DATA: "sunrise":"7:27:02 AM"

SUNSET  DATA: "sunset":"5:05:55 PM"
```

You can further process these strings with `strtok` again if you like. This is just an example code, you can use it to implement your solution.

Comment: dropped the code into my arduino and getting error, invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'  #include <Stdio.h> this doesn't seem to be part of the Arduino libarary

Comment: You do not need `stdio.h` I used that for `printf`. But you need `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc`. Which line gives you that error by the way?

Comment: ok changed the includes and lines 44 & 51 the malloc lines, thanks.

Comment: sorry, not yet was out all day with sons rugby team!!  I included <stdlib.h> but still getting the error on lines 44 & 51.

Comment: Arduino is C++ but it should see standard C libs. But then forget `stdlib.h` and use the C++ way so replace lines like this: `sunrise = malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1);` **with** `sunrise = new char[length + 1]`.

Comment: just been searching I have found this and will try. 

In C++, you need to cast the return of malloc()

char *foo = (char*)malloc(1);

Comment: as a side question and thanks again for your help, why is char* sunrise and not char sunrise.  I believe char* is declaring as a pointer but I have seen examples of char *sunrise? as I look at the code I believe we are reading into variable sunrise as apposed holding a memory location of another varaible?  I am wrong or confused probably in my mind you would have a global variable but am starting to think they don't exist have been reading up last couple of days but don't think I have understood yet

Comment: `char sunrise` would be a single character, but you want to store more than that. And yes `char  *sunrise` is a pointer to a memory location, where the actual data will be stored. This memory can be 1 byte, but it can be 100 byte too. And that is the key, with `malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1)` we allocate as much memory as many characters we want to store.
`sunrise` will hold the starting address of the sunrise data string, if you start reading this location from byte to byte until the terminating null, you will get back the stored data.

Comment: Hi something strange Serial.println(str); only display the number 1 with to dots above it around 4 spaces in, not the whole json response?? also if I serial.println the sunrise and sunset variables I get a compile error??

Comment: have added a screenshot of the garbled get data

Comment: @jason millington First  you forget to call the `readReponseContent(response, sizeof(response));` after sending request to the server. That's why the JSON is garbage. Secondly `Serial.println()` does not equivalent with `printf`. You just have to do this: `Serial.println(sunrise);` to print.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Its working great just need to separate the value from the key.  Thank you ever so much.